# WCF Service ContextMode=PerSession and ConcurrencyMode=Multiple

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service and want to consume in **PerSession  mode and concurrency mode into Multiple**, but while consuming i am getting new service instances  with single thread. Below follows the tested results.

**Per Session/Concurrency Mode - Multiple**
============== Queue name :1111,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:19 Time:4/6/2012 4:01:55 PM==============

============== Queue name :1111,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:2, and Thread:19 Time:4/6/2012 4:01:59 PM==============

============== Queue name :1111,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:3, and Thread:19 Time:4/6/2012 4:02:03 PM==============

============== Queue name :1111,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:4, and Thread:19 Time:4/6/2012 4:02:07 PM==============

============== Queue name :1111,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:5, and Thread:19 Time:4/6/2012 4:02:11 PM==============

**PerCall /Concurrency Mode - single**

============== Queue name :10006,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:13 Time:4/6/2012 2:06:22 PM==============

============== Queue name :10006,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:13 Time:4/6/2012 2:06:26 PM==============

============== Queue name :10006,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:13 Time:4/6/2012 2:06:30 PM==============

============== Queue name :10006,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:13 Time:4/6/2012 2:06:34 PM==============

============== Queue name :10006,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:6 Time:4/6/2012 2:06:38 PM==============

**PerCall Concurrency Mode - Multiple**
============== Queue name :10007,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:6 Time:4/6/2012 2:08:32 PM==============

============== Queue name :10007,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:6 Time:4/6/2012 2:08:36 PM==============

============== Queue name :10007,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:6 Time:4/6/2012 2:08:40 PM==============

============== Queue name :10007,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:6 Time:4/6/2012 2:08:44 PM==============

============== Queue name :10007,  For Service CallServ Instance Created:1, and Thread:6 Time:4/6/2012 2:08:48 PM==============

Get me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Get me a solution." to what? It is very unclear what your "problem" is. What is your expected result? What is your test code doing?

Answer (score 1):

In PerCall instancing, concurrency is not relevant, because each message is processed by a new service instance.

In Session instancing, concurrency is relevant. In case of multiple concurrency, thread-safe code should be written. Please share your code.